# Set up using PPA with Tezos packages from Serokell - Error

Tags: node

I am using Ubuntu, and want to install packages with Tezos binaries from a Launchpad PPA.
Like the steps provided here: https://opentezos.com/deploy-a-node/installation/

First I did `REPO="ppa:serokell/tezos"`

Then I did `sudo add-apt-repository -y $REPO && sudo apt-get update`

Then I did `sudo apt-get install -y tezos-client`
And getting this error at the end of this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares2 nodejs-doc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libev4 libhidapi-libusb0 tezos-sapling-params
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libev4 libhidapi-libusb0 tezos-client tezos-sapling-params
0 upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 269 not upgraded.
Need to get 78.8 MB of archives.
After this operation, 192 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/serokell/tezos/ubuntu focal/main amd64 tezos-sapling-params amd64 2:8.2-0ubuntu4~focal [51.0 MB]
Get:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libev4 amd64 1:4.31-1 [31.2 kB]
Get:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 libhidapi-libusb0 amd64 0.9.0+dfsg-1 [14.5 kB]
Get:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/serokell/tezos/ubuntu focal/main amd64 tezos-client amd64 2:15.1-0ubuntu2~focal [27.7 MB]                                              
Fetched 78.8 MB in 1min 8s (1165 kB/s)                                                                                                                                
Selecting previously unselected package libev4:amd64.
(Reading database ... 41518 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libev4_1%3a4.31-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libev4:amd64 (1:4.31-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libhidapi-libusb0:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../libhidapi-libusb0_0.9.0+dfsg-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libhidapi-libusb0:amd64 (0.9.0+dfsg-1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tezos-sapling-params.
Preparing to unpack .../tezos-sapling-params_2%3a8.2-0ubuntu4~focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tezos-sapling-params (2:8.2-0ubuntu4~focal) ...
Selecting previously unselected package tezos-client.
Preparing to unpack .../tezos-client_2%3a15.1-0ubuntu2~focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tezos-client (2:15.1-0ubuntu2~focal) ...
Setting up libev4:amd64 (1:4.31-1) ...
Setting up libhidapi-libusb0:amd64 (0.9.0+dfsg-1) ...
Setting up tezos-sapling-params (2:8.2-0ubuntu4~focal) ...
Setting up tezos-client (2:15.1-0ubuntu2~focal) ...
 * udev requires devtmpfs support, not started
   ...fail!
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package tezos-client (--configure):
 installed tezos-client package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-0ubuntu9.2) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tezos-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

However I continued and tried to install `sudo apt-get install -y tezos-node`
And again the error at the end of the message here:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  libc-ares2 nodejs-doc
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  tezos-node
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 269 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 28.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 173 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/serokell/tezos/ubuntu focal/main amd64 tezos-node amd64 2:15.1-0ubuntu2~focal [28.7 MB]
Fetched 28.7 MB in 24s (1178 kB/s)                                                                                                                                    
Selecting previously unselected package tezos-node.
(Reading database ... 41539 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../tezos-node_2%3a15.1-0ubuntu2~focal_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking tezos-node (2:15.1-0ubuntu2~focal) ...
Setting up tezos-node (2:15.1-0ubuntu2~focal) ...
Jan 23 01:44:06.352 - node.config.validation: the node configuration has been successfully validated.
Created /var/lib/tezos/node-mainnet/config.json for network: mainnet.
Jan 23 01:44:07.012 - node.config.validation: the node configuration has been successfully validated.
Created /var/lib/tezos/node-ghostnet/config.json for network: ghostnet.
Jan 23 01:44:07.619 - node.config.validation: the node configuration has been successfully validated.
Created /var/lib/tezos/node-limanet/config.json for network: limanet.
Setting up tezos-client (2:15.1-0ubuntu2~focal) ...
 * udev requires devtmpfs support, not started
   ...fail!
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
Failed to connect to bus: Host is down
dpkg: error processing package tezos-client (--configure):
 installed tezos-client package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 tezos-client
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Can I ignore the errors at the bottom or do I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are attempting this using Ubuntu on WSL, is that correct?

If so, it looks like unfortunately you've bumped into a known issue with `udev` there.
Ignoring the error won't work and you won't be able to use `tezos-client`, AFAIK you'll keep seeing that error until you remove the package.

A possible solution can be found [here, on the troubleshooting page from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/troubleshooting#apt-get-upgrade-errors).

Another possible solution, if you have a recent enough version of WSL, is to use WSL with `systemd`, where this issue shouldn't exist. You can find instructions on how to do so [here in an blogpost, once again from Microsoft](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/).

If possible, I'd recommend the latter, because Ubuntu is heavily based on `systemd` and so I think that it'd be the more robust and future-proof option.

Comment: Yes I use WSL v1. Can you please tell me how I can remove the tezos-client package?

I assume when I upgrade to WSL v2, thats what you mean with recent WSL version? Thank you very much for the help, I will read the two links!

Comment: Hey, I tried to do the former solution you posted. Just to try out but do I need to create the file? As it does not exist? - https://askubuntu.com/questions/1451546/file-policy-rc-d-in-wsl1-not-found

Comment: Yes, for the first solution I believe that you need to create that file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: As for removing the `tezos-client` package, you could do so by running `sudo apt-get remove tezos-client`.
TBH I'm not sure if it will be removed automatically in an update from WSL1 to WSL2.

Comment: Unfortunately, the second solution won't work with every WSL2 AFAIK.

You can see how to find your version and update it if needed, in this section of the blogpost I already linked: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/systemd-support-is-now-available-in-wsl/#ensuring-you-are-on-the-right-wsl-version

Comment: Thank you very much. I probably will setup a dedicated VM with Ubuntu instead of using WSL. I guess this will be easier